# PL SQL Package with Procedure, PLS-00323: subprogram or cursor

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, package, plsql-package

Please help me. I am new to PL SQL. I want to Display On Screen all these details

```
Customer.customerNo, Customer.customerName, Customer.custBalance, customerOrder.orderDate, customerOrder.orderNo
```

from 2 tables [Customer, CustomerOrder]. Using the only Package with Procedure. Please help me how can I create such a package?

```
create or replace package my_pkg as
Procedure getAllOrders2(customer_id IN varchar2);
end my_pkg;
/

create or replace package body my_pkg as
Procedure getAllOrders2(customer_id IN varchar2) is
begin
dbms_output.put_line('customer_id is: '||customer_id );
end getAllOrders2;
end my_pkg;
/
```

Output Should be:

Customer Number, Customer Name, Order Number, Order Date, Customer Balance

[Here is the output of all tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRhzs.png)

Comment: What do you need the CustomerOrder table for? "Customer details" are in Customer table ... Also, saying that you "want to get customer details" - how exactly? What do you want to do with them? Just display then on the screen? Put into variables? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a cursor `FOR` loop (why? Because customer can have more than a single order, and - if you use a single `select` statement - you might get the `too_many_rows` error so you'd have to select into a collection or - as in my example - use a loop.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure getallorders2 (par_customer_id in customer.customerno%type)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select c.customerno,
  5                         c.customername,
  6                         c.custbalance,
  7                         o.orderdate,
  8                         o.orderno
  9                  from customer c join customerorder o
 10                    on c.customerno = o.customerno
 11                  where c.customerno = par_customer_id
 12                 )
 13    loop
 14      dbms_output.put_line
 15        (cur_r.customerno   ||', '||
 16         cur_r.customername ||', '||
 17         cur_r.custbalance  ||', '||
 18         cur_r.orderno      ||', '||
 19         to_char(cur_r.orderdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy')
 20        );
 21    end loop;
 22  end;
 23  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> begin
  2    getallorders2('A101');
  3  end;
  4  /
A101, basant, 32000, O101, 04.02.2021

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Now that you know *how*, move that code into a package body.